# How to determine whether class B is a subclass of class A?

Tags: objective-c, ios

It seems that if you develop for Mac OS, `NSObject` has the `isSubclassOfClass` method. But when I check the iOS class reference for the same class, it does not have the method (and Xcode complains about the method).

My current solutions is to put a method `-(void)iAmClassB` in there, and perform a `respondsToSelector:iAmClassB`, but that seems contrived. Am I missing something?

Comment: Methods with a `+` prefix should be called on the class: [A method], and not on the instance: [a method]. Since you did the later, XCode is telling you there is no instance method.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

It is available from iOS 2.0 and later version SDK

```
if ([ClassB isSubclassOfClass:[ClassA class]]) {


    NSLog(@"yes ClassB is SubclassOfClass of ClassA");

}
```

[Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/nsobject_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSObject/isSubclassOfClass%3a):

> **`isSubclassOfClass:`**
>
> Returns a Boolean value that indicates whether the receiving class is
>   a subclass of, or identical to, a given class.
>
> ```
>    + (BOOL)isSubclassOfClass:(Class)aClass
> ```
>
> **Parameters**
>
> aClass
>
> A class object.
>
> **Return Value**
>
> `YES` if the receiving class is a subclass of—or identical to—`aClass`,
>   otherwise `NO`.
>
> **Availability**
>
> Available in iOS 2.0 and later.

Comment: “iOS 2.0 and later”… so every _non-Apple-internal_ SDK version.

Answer (score 5):

```
id a= ...;
if([a isKindOfClass:[A class]]){
     ...
}
```

should do the job. You rarely needs to see if it's really a *sub* class. See [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/NSObject).

Comment: I think you misinterpreted this method's name.  `isKindOfClass:` still tells you if it's really a sub-class, it just operates on an object instance instead of a `Class` object.  That is, `if ([a isKindOfClass:A.class])` does the same thing as `if (a.class == A.class || [a.class isSubclassOfClass:A.class])`.  _(Dot-syntax for clarity; assumes iOS 8's version of the NSObject protocol.)_