# How to check a Class (metaclass object) object is equal with another class object

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa

There's `Class` object in Cocoa which is <strike>meta</strike>class object. As I know, this is actually Objective-C class, but there's no specification.
So How can I check equality between two class objects?

```
Class a = [@"" class];
Class b = [[NSObject alloc] init] class];

BOOL c = (a == b);  // Is this right?
```

Comment: Just to be clear, the `class` method returns a class, not a metaclass.

Comment: @jlehr I discovered critical mistake on my code. Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to determine whether class B is a subclass of class A?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7282249/how-to-determine-whether-class-b-is-a-subclass-of-class-a)

Comment: Your question doesn't mention anything about subclassing, class hierarchy, or inheritance. Class equality *can* be tested with `==`, especially in iOS, where we can't dynamically load bundles.

Comment: @jlehr Ah yes, you're right. I will just link the posting in my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a method exactly for this purpose. Cited from [Apple's current official reference manual page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/nsobject_class/reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSObject/isSubclassOfClass:).

```
-[NSObject isSubclassOfClass:]
```

> Returns a Boolean value that indicates whether the receiving class is a subclass of, or identical to, a given class.

Anyway, this includes subclasses, and if you want *exact* equality comparison, you should use another method.

See also for more about the method: [How to determine whether class B is a subclass of class A?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7282249/how-to-determine-whether-class-b-is-a-subclass-of-class-a)

Answer (score 9):

There is a method on NSObject for this.  isKindOfClass

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSObject/isKindOfClass:

```
[a isKindofClass:[b class]];
```

You can read more about reflection in objective-c here

http://osmorphis.blogspot.com/2009/05/reflection-in-objective-c.html

Answer (score 4):

madmik3 is correct if you want to include inheritance. With your example above, if you tested [a isKindOfClass:[b class]] it would test YES because NSString inherits from NSObject.

If you want to test for exact class equality you can use isMemberOfClass:, which does NOT include inheritance. In your example [a isMemberOfClass:[b class]] will test as NO since NSString is a different class than NSObject.

In my experience it is typical to test using the class method, e.g. [a isMemberOfClass:[NSString class]].

Enjoy,

Damien